# Split the String in Powershell

Tags: powershell, split, strsplit

[image]I have a code which gives me below output.

```
 assigned_to
@{display_value=Raju Mishra link=https://googleprod.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user/6486d149db70ee40db88b9d10f961969
```

}

Desired Output

```
Username
Raju Mishra
```

With below command, I am getting below output.

```
Select @{name="Username";Expression={($_.assigned_to -split '=')[1] -join ' ' }}
```

The Output which I am getting with it is:

```
Username                                                                                                                            
Raju Mishra; link
```

Comment: If that command you;re using is retrieving an object you'd be better getting the correct value with the command instead of trying to split the object as a string afterwards.

Comment: could you provide me the command to do it. I am not too good with Powershell

Comment: I don;t know what command you;re using....

Comment: @GURUSINGH - *I have a command which gives me below output* - add the command to your question.

Comment: @ Lieven Keersmaekers   Select @{name="Username";Expression={($_.assigned_to -split '=')[1] -join ' ' }}.

Comment: @Scepticalist Please find the command -- Select @{name="Username";Expression={($_.assigned_to -split '=')[1] -join ' ' }}

Comment: What does `(... -First 1).assigned_to.GetType()` Return? What is the output of `(... -First 1).assigned_to | gm`?

Comment: Thanks @LievenKeersmaekers.  I changed the bit in my code and it works.

Comment: No problem offcourse but what did you have to change :)

Comment: Update your question with the code from your image.

Comment: I'm coming to this late, and I understand you're already past the issue.  Hope you don't mind my comment.  I think the assigned_to property may itself be a rich object, not a string.  `-Split` may have implicitly converted to a string, maybe explaining the hash like object syntax from your question.  So, I wonder if a more simple property expression like: `@{Name = "Username"; Expression= { $_.assigned_to.display_value }` would've worked? Assuming `.display_value` is a string.